# JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA Deployment Failed - JBAS015871

Tags: jboss

I would have a problem concerning the deployment of my .war file (WebArchive). The application is developed with Spring Framework 4.0.3 (only Spring MVC is used) and cxf is used for a webservice- Client. It's a really small application and local deployment works fine (JBoss AS 7.1). 
The deployment at productive environment (JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA in domain mode) arises with following Error above.
Actually I dont know what to do - there is no error output.
It would be great if someone could give me a hint what to do.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I have found out what the problem is, but I couldn't solve it, I have a WebService- Client class annotated with @WebService:

```
/*@javax.jws.WebService(
                  serviceName = "RemoteUserStoreManagerService",
                  portName = "RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint",
                  targetNamespace = "http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org",
                  wsdlLocation = "https://...:.../services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl",
                  endpointInterface = "org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.RemoteUserStoreManagerServicePortType")*/
```

public class RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap12EndpointImpl implements     RemoteUserStoreManagerServicePortType {

If I comment it with /* ... */ like above, everything works fine.
Does anyone know what to do in order to solve this issue?
Thanks a lot!!

```
07:59:04,234 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=org.....service....ServiceHttpsSoap12EndpointImpl
 address=...
 implementor=...ServiceHttpsSoap12EndpointImpl
 serviceName={...}...
 portName={...}...
 annotationWsdlLocation=...
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
07:59:04,382 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating Service {...... from WSDL: ......
07:59:04,606 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Setting the server's publish address to be ......
07:59:04,657 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS024074: WSDL published to: file:/D:/jboss...
07:59:04,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.port-component-link
07:59:04,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."..."."org.....ws.service.ServiceHttpsSoap12EndpointImpl"
07:59:04,673 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) JBAS018210: Register web context: /myApplication
07:59:04,680 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApplication]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
07:59:04,690 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApplication]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
07:59:04,780 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 04 07:59:04 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
07:59:04,849 WARNING [InfoLogging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) 'SSOAgentPropertiesFilePath' not configured
07:59:06,440 WARN  [org.openid4java.server.RealmVerifier] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) RP discovery / realm validation disabled; 
07:59:06,475 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApplication]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
07:59:06,475 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
07:59:06,479 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 04 07:59:06 CET 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
07:59:06,482 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
07:59:06,733 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
07:59:06,946 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Creating Service {.......org}StoreManagerService from WSDL: ...://...StoreManagerService?wsdl
07:59:07,382 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 906 ms
07:59:07,772 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (host-controller-connection-threads - 14) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "org.*.war" was rolled back with no failure message 
07:59:07,775 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) JBAS018224: Unregister web context: /myApplication
07:59:07,777 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) MODCLUSTER000021: All pending requests drained from default-host:/myApplication in 0,0 seconds
07:59:07,778 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApplication]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
07:59:07,778 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 04 07:59:06 CET 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
07:59:07,781 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApplication]] (ServerServic`enter code here`e Thread Pool -- 442) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
07:59:07,782 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 442) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 04 07:59:04 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
07:59:07,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015540: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."org.*.war"."org.....service.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap12EndpointImpl"
07:59:07,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015540: Stopping service jboss.ws.port-component-link
07:59:18,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myApplication (runtime-name: *.war) in 10997ms
```

Comment: Do you have created custom modules in the development environment?

Comment: check the access to  `"https://...:.../services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl"` in prod servers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have access to https://...:.../services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl - this is OK, What do you mean with "custom modules"?

Comment: For example, spring is deployed into war or are using a jboss module

Comment: In my application spring modules are artefacts in my project. Currently I don't have any dependencies to JBoss Modules - all is in the .war file. It is really hard to guess what is getting wrong with the deployment at JBoss in domain mode. In the development environment at my labtop locally with JBoss in standalone mode everything works fine. Actually I don't know what to check or try out - I would be very glad if someone could give me a hint concerning this issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: `@javax.jws.WebService` is not a web service client, this is a web service implementation. Are you using in wsdllocation pointing to the same web service?